# Piwik file permissions and .htaccess

Tags: permissions, logging, analytics, piwik

I'm in the process of setting up a [Piwik 1.0](http://piwik.org/) installation and wanted to ask if someone knows what the minimal file permission (Linux) are, that Piwik needs. Does it need any write access to the folder it is installed or to any of the files therein?

Also I'm wondering why the `libs` and `misc` folder don't have a `.htaccess` file is this on purpose or an oversight in the installer?

btw. there is no piwik tag yet. And I can't create because of reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver user needs write access to these directories:

- `/piwik/tmp/templates_c`
- `/piwik/tmp/cache`
- `/piwik/tmp/assets`

And this file:
 - `/piwik/config/config.ini.php`

About the .htaccess: I don't know. .htaccess is Apache-specific though.

Comment: thanks for the info. I can't upvote your answer yet because I don't have enough rep